# Нахождение кратчайшего пути в лабиринте (массиве) с визуализацией в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, numpy, анализ-данных

Получила в университете следующее задание.

1. Создайте лабиринт в Python
   Используйте соответствующую структуру данных для внутреннего представления лабиринта, предпочтительно массив NumPy.
2. Визуализируйте лабиринт
   Самый простой способ визуализировать лабиринт - преобразовать его в символьное / строковое представление (ASCII-art) и просто записать его в консоль или вывод записной книжки с помощью функции print (), как показано выше. Если у вас уже есть продвинутый опыт работы с Python, вы также можете полагаться на графические представления.
3. Определить путь
   Путь может быть получен эвристическим или точным способом. Вам разрешено использовать для этой цели соответствующую библиотеку, но вы также можете реализовать алгоритм самостоятельно
   .
4. Распечатайте путь
   а. Текстовая форма (координаты): (x1, y1) -> (x2, y2) ->
   б. Графическая (ASCII или растровая) форма, в зависимости от того, что вы выбрали на шаге 2).

В интернете нашла код и преобразовала его под свои данные:

```
M = 20 # Rows
N = 50 # Columns
def isSafe(grid,visited,x,y):
    if grid[x][y]=='#' or visited[x][y]==True:
        return False # Unsafe
    return True # Safe

def isValid(x,y):
    if x<M and y<N and x>=0 and y>=0:
        return True # Valid
    return False # Invalid

def solve(grid,visited,i,j,dest_x,dest_y,curr_dist,min_dist,shortestPath,currentPath):
    if i==dest_x and j==dest_y: # if destination is found, update min_dist
        if curr_dist<min_dist[0]: # If a shorter distance is found
            min_dist[0] = curr_dist # Update distance
            shortestPath.clear() # Update path
            shortestPath.extend(currentPath)
            shortestPath.append((dest_y,dest_x)) # Push the destination coordinates
        return

    # set (i, j) cell as visited
    visited[i][j] = True
    currentPath.append((j,i))

    # go to bottom cell
    if isValid(i + 1, j) and isSafe(grid,visited,i + 1, j):
        solve(grid,visited,i + 1, j, dest_x, dest_y, curr_dist + 1,min_dist,shortestPath,currentPath)
    # go to right cell
    if isValid(i, j + 1) and isSafe(grid,visited,i, j + 1):
        solve(grid,visited,i, j + 1, dest_x, dest_y, curr_dist + 1,min_dist,shortestPath,currentPath)

    # go to top cell
    if isValid(i - 1, j) and isSafe(grid,visited,i - 1, j):
        solve(grid,visited,i - 1, j, dest_x, dest_y, curr_dist + 1,min_dist,shortestPath,currentPath)

    # go to left cell
    if isValid(i, j - 1) and isSafe(grid,visited,i, j - 1):
        solve(grid,visited,i, j - 1, dest_x, dest_y, curr_dist + 1,min_dist,shortestPath,currentPath)
    visited[i][j] = False
    currentPath.pop()

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    min_dist = [9e10] # Start from infinity
    shortestPath = [] # It will contain the path (y,x) tuples
    currentPath = [] # It will store the current path temporarily
    grid = [
        ['-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','T','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|','S',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-']
        ]
    visited = []
    for i in range(M):
        _list = list()
        for j in range(N):
            _list.append(False)
        visited.append(_list)
    solve(grid,visited,M-1,0,0,N-1,0,min_dist,shortestPath,currentPath)
    print("Minimum distance: ",min_dist[0])
    print("Path: [",end=" ")
    for path in shortestPath:
        print('('+str(path[0])+','+str(path[1])+')',end=' ')
    print("]")
```

Получаю ошибку:
`list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`

Пробовала и такую программу:

```
from collections import deque
maze = [
        ['-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','T','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['|','S',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|']
        ['-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-']
        ]


def print_field(field, path = None):
  field = maze.readlines()
n = len(field)
m = len(field[0]) - 1
s = None
t = None
for i in range(n):
  field[i] = field[i].strip()
  if field[i].find('S') !=-1:
    s = (i, field[i].find('S'))
  if field[i].find('T') != -1:
    t = (i, field[i].find('T'))

print_field(field)
print(s,t)

def bfs(field, S, T):
  n = len(field)
  m = len(field[0])
  INF = 10**9
  delta = [(0,-1), (0,1), (1,0), (-1,0)]
  d = [[INF]]*m for _ in range(n)]
  p = [[None]]*m for _ in range(n)]
  used = [[False]*m for _ in range(n)]
  queue = dequeue()

  d[s[0]][s[1]] = 0
  used[s[0]][s[1]] = True
  queue.append(s)
  while len(queue) != 0:
    x, y = queue.popleft()
    for dx, dy in delta:
      nx, ny = x+dx, y+dy
      if 0 < nx < n and 0 < ny < m and not used[nx][ny] and field[nx][ny] != '#':
        d[nx][ny] = d[x][y] + 1
        p[nx][ny] = (x, y))
        used[nx][ny] = True
        queue.append((nx, ny))
  print(d[t[0]][t[1]])
  cur = t
  path = []
  while cure is not None:
    path.append(cur)
    cur = p[cur[0]][cur[1]]
    path.reverse()
    print_field(field, path[1:-1])
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
  File "<ipython-input-7-c2320f90efab>", line 49
    d = [[INF]]*m for _ in range(n)]
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Уже голову сломала, ничего не получается! В университете с подобными задачами не работали, программирую в Питоне недавно, поэтому самой разобраться сложно. Буду очень благодарна за помощь!

Если знаете другие способы нахождения кратчайшего пути с использованием NumPy, то поделитесь информацией, пожалуйста! (такой вид у лабиринта [image: фото] был определен преподавателем)

Comment: Там похоже лишняя закрывающая скобка. Попробуйте так `d = [[INF]*m for _ in range(n)]` и в следующей строке по тому же принципу. Можете на третью подобную строку глянуть, там скобки вроде правильно стоят.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, эта ошибка ушла! Но теперь у меня в обоих кодах одинаковая ошибка : "list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple" :(